# Convert the lists in multiple columns to rows in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have df with three columns:

- Col 0 - sentence row num
- Col 1 - Sentence converted to list
- Col 2 - list of annotations

| Col 0 | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [This, is, sentence] | [l1, l2, l3] |
| 2 | [This, is, sentence, too] | [l1, l2, l3, l4] |

I would like to convert Col1 and Col2 and move each row and its respective annotation to separate row:

| Col 0 | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This | l1 |
| 1 | is | l2 |
| 1 | sentence | l3 |
| 2 | This | l1 |
| 2 | is | l2 |
| 2 | sentence | l3 |
| 2 | too | l4 |

When I use `explode` on each column separately one of the columns always does not change.

```
data2['Col1_exploded'] = (data['Col1'].explode('Col1'))
```

And this option does not work too:

```
data2[['Col1_exploded', 'Col2_exploded']] = (data[['Col1', 'Col2']].explode('Col1', 'Col2'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass list of column names to `explode`:

```py
>>> df.explode(['Col1', 'Col2'])

   Col 0      Col1 Col2
0      1      This   l1
0      1        is   l2
0      1  sentence   l3
1      2      This   l1
1      2        is   l2
1      2  sentence   l3
1      2       too   l4
```

Answer (score 1):

you were really close ! this works for me :

```
df.explode(['Col1', 'Col2'])
```

result :

```
    Col 0   Col1    Col2
0   1   This    l1
0   1   is  l2
0   1   sentence    l3
1   2   This    l1
1   2   is  l2
1   2   sentence    l3
1   2   too l4
```